# rails mechanize run through each url in a postgres table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, mechanize

*Edit:
Per my comment below, I guess a better question would be, 'What would the proper way be to have mechanize go through each url and update its name column? (each name would be unique to the url)' Below is what I've been basing my exercise on. *

---

I have a postgres table that goes like...
| name (string) | url (text) |

The url column is already populated with various url's and appears like this one:
http://www.a4apps.com/Websites/SampleCalendar/tabid/89/ctl/Register/Default.aspx

I am trying to run a mechanize rake task that will run through each url and update the name based on the text it finds at a css tag.

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fetch css from db urls"
  task :fetch_css => :environment do

    require 'rubygems'
    require 'mechanize'
    require 'open-uri'

    agent = Mechanize.new
    url = Mytable.pluck(:url)
    agent.get(url)
    agent.page.search('#dnn_ctr444_ContentPane').each do |item|
      name = item.css('.EventNextPrev:nth-child(1) a').text
      Mytable.update(:name => name)
    end 
  end
end
```

When I run the rake task it returns:

```
rake aborted!
bad URI(is not URI?): %255B%2522http://www.a4apps.com/Websites/SampleCalendar/tabid/89/Default.aspx%2522,%2520%2522http://www.a4apps.com/Websites/SampleCalendar/tabid/89/ctl/Privacy/Default.aspx%2522,%2520%2522http://www.a4apps.com/Websites/SampleCalendar/tabid/89/ctl/Terms/Default.aspx%2522,%2520%2522http://www.a4apps.com/Websites/SampleCalendar/tabid/89/ctl/Register/Default.aspx%2522%255D
```

Thanks for any help. If there's any way I can make the question easier to answer, please let me know.
Mike

Comment: After working on this for a while I think maybe I am doing the rake completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I feel a little lonely answering my own questions lately but I'll post my answers in the event that someone else finds themselves in the same bind. Also, maybe others will tell me if my solution has any fatal flaws that I am not seeing yet. Here is my final rake that seems to be working, getting urls from my table, running mechanize on them and updating the table with the info found at the urls...

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fetch css from db urls"
  task :fetch_css => :environment do

    Mytable.all.each do |info|  # for each row do...
      require 'rubygems'
      require 'mechanize'
      require 'open-uri'
      agent = Mechanize.new
      agent.get(info.url)             # get the url column data for the current db row...
      nombre = agent.page.search('.EventNextPrev:nth-child(1) a').text  # plug it into mech.
      info.update_attributes(:name => nombre)  # and update the db with the css result.
    end

  end
end
```

Thanks.
Mike